# error: "set KERNEL_DIR in your phpunit.xml" but KERNEL_DIR is set "<server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="./">" in phpunit.xml.dist

Tags: symfony, phpunit

while trynig to PHPUnit functional test I got
error:

```
1) TreningBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex
RuntimeException: Either set KERNEL_DIR in your phpunit.xml according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#your-first-functional-test or override the WebTestCase::createKernel() method.
```

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/testing.html saying:

> if your kernel is in a non-standard directory, you'll need to modify
>   your phpunit.xml.dist

I've got files `phpunit.xml.dist` and `AppKErnel.php` in deafult Symfony (2.8) place, inside `app\` directory. Anyway I added below line in `app/phpunit.xml.dist`:

```
<php>
     <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="./" />
</php>
```

with results same error .

installed packages:

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.7
doctrine/cache                       v1.6.0
doctrine/collections                 v1.3.0
doctrine/common                      v2.6.1
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.4
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.6.2
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.3.0
doctrine/inflector                   v1.1.0
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.5
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.4
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler v2.1.2
ircmaxell/password-compat            v1.0.4
jdorn/sql-formatter                  v1.2.17
monolog/monolog                      1.19.0
myclabs/deep-copy                    1.5.1
paragonie/random_compat              v2.0.2
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock    2.0.4
phpspec/prophecy                     v1.6.0
phpunit/php-code-coverage            3.3.2
phpunit/php-file-iterator            1.4.1
phpunit/php-text-template            1.2.1
phpunit/php-timer                    1.0.8
phpunit/php-token-stream             1.4.8
phpunit/phpunit                      5.3.4
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects         3.1.3
phpunit/phpunit-skeleton-generator   2.0.1
psr/log                              1.0.0
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup   1.0.0
sebastian/comparator                 1.2.0
sebastian/diff                       1.4.1
sebastian/environment                1.3.7
sebastian/exporter                   1.2.1
sebastian/global-state               1.1.1
sebastian/object-enumerator          1.0.0
sebastian/recursion-context          1.0.2
sebastian/resource-operations        1.0.0
sebastian/version                    1.0.6
sensio/distribution-bundle           v5.0.6
sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v3.0.16
sensio/generator-bundle              v3.0.6
sensiolabs/security-checker          v3.0.2
swiftmailer/swiftmailer              v5.4.2
symfony/monolog-bundle               2.11.1
symfony/phpunit-bridge               v2.8.6
symfony/polyfill-apcu                v1.2.0
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu            v1.2.0
symfony/polyfill-mbstring            v1.2.0
symfony/polyfill-php54               v1.2.0
symfony/polyfill-php55               v1.2.0
symfony/polyfill-php56               v1.2.0
symfony/polyfill-php70               v1.2.0
symfony/polyfill-util                v1.2.0
symfony/security-acl                 v3.0.0
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v2.3.11
symfony/symfony                      v2.8.6
twig/twig                            v1.24.0
```

with absolute path:

```
<server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="C:\wamp\www\treningPHPUnitSymfony2.8\app" />
```

same error.

Comment: Did you ever come right with this?

Comment: @SarahRichardson Yes, problem was related to IDE. In IDE You must give path to phpunit.xml.dist while configuring Test Configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Using `Symfony 2.8.17` our kernel is in  `/app` and `phpunit.xml.dist` on the same level.
So we added;

```
<php>
    ....
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app" />
</php>
```

PS: Extra info;
Due to our setup we also required to use `putenv("X_ENV=test")` to get config details to complete the test.